# How to make this if statement true so it does not catch an Exception?

Tags: java, exception

I'm trying to write an if statement that both catches an exception and does not catch an exception, I have caught the exception but I cannot figure out how to make the condition true so that it does not catch the exception and returns the desired value. Here is the code:

**Main**

```
package QuestionEditor;

public class Main {
    public Main() {
        super();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Wolf wolfExample = new Wolf();        

        try {            

            Food vegFood =  new Food("Spinach");
                    System.out.println("************Wolf Exception example************");
            wolfExample.eat(vegFood);
            //wolfExample.eat(vegFood);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: Add catch code
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("************Wolf Non-Exception example************");
         Food Meat = new Food("Steak");
         System.out.println("Wolves eat " + wolfExample.eat(Meat));
    }
}
```

**Animal**

```
package QuestionEditor;

abstract public class Animal 
{

String name;
int age;  
String noise;

abstract public void makeNoise();

public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String newName) {
        name = newName;
    }

abstract public Food eat(Food x) throws Exception;

}

package QuestionEditor;
public class Carnivore extends Animal
{

   public Food eat(Food x) throws Exception
    { 
        if (x instanceof Meat) {
                return x;
            } else {
               throw new Exception("Carnivores only eat meat!");
            }

    }
   public String toString(Food x) {
    return x.toString();
   }

    public void makeNoise()  
    {
        noise = null;
    }
    public String getNoise()  
    {
        return noise;
    }   
}
```

**Food**

```
package QuestionEditor;

public class Food {

    //field that stores the name of the food
    public String name; 

    //constructor that takes the name of the food as an argument
    public Food(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

**Meat**

```
package QuestionEditor;

public class Meat extends Food 
{
    public Meat(String name) {
        super(name);
    }

    public String getName() {
        return super.getName();
    }
}
```

**Wolf**

```
package QuestionEditor;

public class Wolf extends Carnivore
{

Wolf()   
{
    name = "Alex";
    age = 4;

}
    public void makeNoise()  
    {
        noise = "Woof!";
    }
    public String getNoise()  
    {
        return noise;
    }
    public String getName() 
    {
        return name;
    }  
    public int getAge()
    {
        return age;
    }

    public Food eat(Food x) throws Exception
    { 
        if (x instanceof Meat) {
                return x;
            } else {
               throw new Exception("Carnivores only eat meat!");
            }
    }    
}
```

**Output**

```
************Wolf Exception example************
java.lang.Exception: Carnivores only eat meat!
************Wolf Non-Exception example************
    at QuestionEditor.Wolf.eat(Wolf.java:34)
    at QuestionEditor.Main.main(Main.java:15)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - unreported exception java.lang.Exception; must be caught or declared to be thrown
    at QuestionEditor.Main.main(Main.java:25)
C:\Users\lee-pc\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
```

It wants me to catch Meat as an exception but I want to make it so that Meat is not an exception and relates to the Meat condition in the if statement which looks like this:

```
public Food eat(Food x) throws Exception

{ 
    if (x instanceof Meat) {
            return x;
        } else {
           throw new Exception("Carnivores only eat meat!");
        }    
}
```

Should be true of this:

```
Food Meat = new Food("Steak");
        System.out.println("Wolves eat " + wolfExample.eat(Meat));
```

The desired output would be:

```
 ************Wolf Exception example************
    java.lang.Exception: Carnivores only eat meat!
    ************Wolf Non-Exception example************
    Wolves eat Meat
```

I understand that I have made an error but I'm struggling to figure out how to resolve it, any help would be great, thanks.

Comment: You have too much code here. Please post a [mcve] so your issue is a lot clearer.

Comment: you have a salad with name Conventions, why eat method will return the same you give as parameter?

Comment: Just don't throw an exception, you could simply make your eat method return a boolean value: true if the food is OK, false otherwise.

Comment: The purpose of the assignment is to demonstrate the use of exceptions so I have no choice but to do it this way unfortunately.

Comment: '... both catches an exception and does not catch an exception' is a contradiction in terms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why you don't get `"Wolves eat Meat"` printed, but an Exception is that you still need a `try - catch` block around *every* call to `.eat()` even when you know that the Exception won't be thrown.

The exception you are getting here before the line is printed is a `RuntimeException` because the code is not compilable

The second reson why this is not working, is that the "meat" you are giving the wolf is of the type `Food` and not `Meat`:

```
Food meat = new Food("Steak");   // no matter what name you give the food, it is still of the class Food
```

These little changes will make it work:

```
Food meat = new Meat("Steak");    // you create a Meat object and store it in a Food variable (so to speak)
try{     
    System.out.println("Wolves eat " + wolfExample.eat(meat));   // must be surrounded by a try-catch block
}catch(Exception ex){
    Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);  // better way to log the exception than ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

BTW: variables should start with a small letter (`Food meat` instead of `Food Meat` .. otherwise how do you know if `Meat` is the class or your variable? ;)

**EDIT**
another sidenote: your class `Food` should override the `toString()` method to be properly printable. Otherwise `System.out.println(meat)` will just end up in something like `com.my.package.Meat@5113de03`

Comment: Thanks, this worked and helped a lot. The only issue I'm getting is that the output is `Wolves eat QuestionEditor.Meat@6d06d69c` instead of `Wolves eat Meat`.

Comment: yes, have a look at my edit - best practice here would be to create a `public String toString()` method in your class `Food` that simply returns the name of the food or something. Then it would say: `Wolves eat Steak`

Comment: glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

If a method has the potential to throw a checked exception, this is declared in its signature.  If you call a method that declares the potential to throw an exception, you must either provide a handler for that exception or declare that you, too, could throw it.  The fact that you, as you're writing the exercise, happen to know that you should not get the exception in this case does not relieve you of this requirement.

What you have to do is put the code that calls the method in a `try` block, and provide a `catch` block for the checked exception that the method declares it could throw (`Exception` in this case).  This does not mean that the exception *will* get thrown - in this case it won't - but Java insists on knowing what it should do if it were thrown.

Some people - notably the Spring community - don't really like this behavior, so they use unchecked exceptions for just about everything.  (Unchecked exceptions are those derived form `RuntimeException` or `Error`, though `Error` is generally reserved for more severe situations.)  The original design of Java, though, was to ensure that every checked exception should eventually reach a handler.

Comment: I've added a try and catch block but it still believes it's an Exception even though the food is called Meat and Meat should just return the value of Meat instead of throwing an Exception?